# How to find the version of a dmg file on macos

Tags: macos, installation

On a windows, a installer's version can be found by Right-Click-> Properties -> Detail Tab -> Version and Build Number.

How can I find the same info of a dmg installer on macOS ?

Comment: dmg files are just containers (specifically, they're disk images), they don't have version numbers. Now, a dmg might *contain* something like an app or an installer package (.pkg or .mpkg), and *that* might have a version number; if so, you can find it by opening the disk image, selecting the file inside it, and choosing File menu -> Get Info (or Command-I) in the Finder.